# .unwrap() doesn't work after .append().load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently doing this:

```
$("div#js-product-list .products.row").append($("<div>").load('http://andreisdev.tk/alexstan/en/2-home?page=' + page_nr + ' .products.row article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature'));
```

Then I am incrementing the `page_nr`, that is not important in this question because it works.

After that I am trying to unwrap the `article`s just loaded in the page to make them siblings with the other `article`s already in the page, since load overrides the selection you make, I had to make that `div` at the end of all my current articles.

I am trying to unwrap them this way:

```
$('article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature ~ div article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature').unwrap();
```

So basically I am selecting the div just appended as sibling to the current `article`s I had then I'm selecting the `article`s just loaded inside that new div and trying to unwrap them.

If I am doing this in the console, first typing the command with `.append().load()` and run it, then the `.unwrap()` one it works totally fine, if I am inserting and runnning them both at the same time though it does not work, same thing that happens from my .js file.

I kind of succeded with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature ~ div article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature').unwrap(); 
}, 500);
```

But there has to be a direct way of doing it.

`EDIT !!!`

Since the comments won't be seen by too many, here's the response:

`$("div#js-product-list .products.row").append($("<div>").load(''+link+' .products.row article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature', function() {
            $('article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature ~ div article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature').unwrap();
        }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `load()` is asynchronous, so you're attempting to unwrap elements that don't exist yet. This is why using the timeout to delay the logic works.

A better solution is to use the callback argument of `load()` to provide a function to execute your unwrap logic *after* the content has been added to the DOM. Like this:

```
$("div#js-product-list .products.row").append($("<div>").load('http://andreisdev.tk/alexstan/en/2-home?page=' + page_nr + ' .products.row article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature', function() {
  $('article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature ~ div article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature').unwrap();
}));
```

Comment: The thing is that you said callback of `load()` and you made that function work inside the `append()` function.

Wouldn't it be good to do it like this:


`$("div#js-product-list .products.row").append("<div>").load('http://andreisdev.tk/alexstan/en/2-home?page=' + page_nr + ' .products.row article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature', function() {
            $('article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature ~ div article.product-miniature.js-product-miniature').unwrap();
        });`

Comment: I've just copied the code you used in the question. There may be better ways of appending the content you require, but there's nothing inherently wrong with what you've done.

Comment: If there are better ways, please suggest any because I am open to anything at this point. And thank you for your response.

Comment: It depends on the output you're trying to achieve. As I mentioned above, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, if your goal is to wrap the loaded content in a `div`.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean about the code in your comment - that was my mistake. I placed the closing parenthesis in the wrong place

Comment: The thing is that I have to use the callback, because it is asynchronous, I just figured I have done a mistake in my code with the .append($("<div>").load()) because it wasn't intended to be this way either, only now I saw what I have done.
I shall get to the end of this and post my solution, so if anyone else ever comes across this it won't be such a headache.